# Are deformations of quotients of local rings embedded?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

In Hartshorne's book "Deformation Theory" one can find a statement (inside the proof of Theorem 10.1) that every deformation $X' \to Spec(C)$ of an affine scheme $$X = Spec(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_i)) \to Spec(k)$$ for $C \to k$ is in fact isomorphic to an embedded deformation, i.e., it arises from lifting of the elements $f_j$ to $C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Is this also true for closed subschemes of regular local rings? Namely, if one fixes a regular local rings $R/k$ together with a flat $C$-lifting $R'/C$ of $R$.  Does any flat lifting of $Spec(R/(f_1,\ldots,f_i))$ necessarily come from a lifting of $f_j$'s to $R'$? Maybe, there are some special cases concerning $R$ being essentially of finite type over some field $k$? Is there any additional condition one can impose on the sequence $(f_1,\ldots,f_i)$ (regular sequence? for example) to make such a statement true?

Answer (score 1):

Not true in general. For example, say $k$ is a non perfect field and $C = k[\epsilon]$ (ring of dual numbers) and $R = k'$ is a finite extension of $k$ and $R' = k'[\epsilon]$ with obvious structure of $C$-algebra. Then your statement would mean that every deformation of $k'$ would be trivial which isn't true in general. For example if $k' = k[x]/(x^p - \lambda)$ for a non-$p$th power $\lambda$ of $k$, then the deformation $C[x]/(x^p - \lambda - \epsilon x)$ is not a trival deformation.

What is sufficient is to assume that $R$ is formally smooth over $k$ as defined in [Definition Tag 07EB](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07EB). I am not going to explain in full why this is sufficient. There are some criteria that allows one to check this ([Proposition Tag 07NQ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NQ) and [Proposition Tag 07PM](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07PM)) but the easiest thing is to remember that it is true if (1) if $R$ is the localization of a smooth $k$-algebra, or if (2) $R$ is a regular local ring and the residue field of $R$ is a separable extension of $k$.

Conclusion: in characteristic zero it works. Good luck!